# Get counts of all tables in a schema

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to get the record counts of all tables in a schema. I am having trouble writing the PL/SQL. Here is what I have done so far, but I am getting errors. Please suggest any changes:

```
DECLARE
v_owner varchar2(40);
v_table_name varchar2(40);

cursor get_tables is
select distinct table_name,user
from user_tables
where lower(user) = 'SCHEMA_NAME';


begin

open get_tables;
fetch get_tables into v_table_name,v_owner;

    INSERT INTO STATS_TABLE(TABLE_NAME,SCHEMA_NAME,RECORD_COUNT,CREATED)
    SELECT v_table_name,v_owner,COUNT(*),TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YY') FROM         v_table_name;

CLOSE get_tables;

END;
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your errors instead of trying to make us guess.  Fortunately you have made a couple of classic bloomers so it's an easy game this time.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This should do it:

```
declare
    v_count integer;
begin

    for r in (select table_name, owner from all_tables
              where owner = 'SCHEMA_NAME') 
    loop
        execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || r.table_name 
            into v_count;
        INSERT INTO STATS_TABLE(TABLE_NAME,SCHEMA_NAME,RECORD_COUNT,CREATED)
        VALUES (r.table_name,r.owner,v_count,SYSDATE);
    end loop;

end;
```

I removed various bugs from your code.

**Note:** For the benefit of other readers, Oracle does not provide a table called `STATS_TABLE`, you would need to create it.

Comment: Small typo: The l_count should in INSERT values should be v_count

Comment: A couple of variations to suggest ... I've recently grown fond of constructing the SQL to be executed in the implicit cursor's  selet clause, as it allows you to run the select and see what statement is generated. One might also construct the insert statement as dynamic SQL and combine the insert and select into a single operation. Just a couple of options ...

Comment: ORA-06550: line 10, column 21:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 10, column 9:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: I got the same error as with @SherlockSpreadsheets here.

Comment: @Benjamin Perhaps you don't have a table called `STATS_TABLE` like the OP does?  This would be a table you would create yourself.

Comment: Okay I won't be able to do that in my case as I'm working on a read-only DB mode for that specific DB. Solution below worked out for me though. Thanks.

Answer (score 81):

This can be done with a single statement and some XML magic:

```
select table_name, 
       to_number(extractvalue(xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '||owner||'.'||table_name)),'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) as count
from all_tables
where owner = 'FOOBAR'
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you :)

Comment: Take note that some table_name might be case-sensitive, so the inner-query might fail if you do not surround it in double-quotes, i.e. `'select count(1) c from '||owner||'."'||table_name ||'"'`

Comment: Lovely stuff. That's the only solution that worked on Oracle 9.

Answer (score 12):

```
select owner, table_name, num_rows, sample_size, last_analyzed from all_tables;
```

This is the fastest way to retrieve the row counts but there are a few important caveats:

1. NUM_ROWS is only 100% accurate if statistics were gathered in 11g and above with `ESTIMATE_PERCENT => DBMS_STATS.AUTO_SAMPLE_SIZE` (the default), or in earlier versions with `ESTIMATE_PERCENT => 100`.  See [this post](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/how_does_auto_sample_size) for an explanation of how 
   the AUTO_SAMPLE_SIZE algorithm works in 11g.
2. Results were generated as of `LAST_ANALYZED`, the current results may be different.

Answer (score 8):

If you want simple SQL for Oracle (e.g. have XE with no XmlGen) go for a simple 2-step:

```
select ('(SELECT ''' || table_name || ''' as Tablename,COUNT(*) FROM "' || table_name || '") UNION') from USER_TABLES;
```

Copy the entire result and replace the last UNION with a semi-colon (';'). Then as the 2nd step execute the resulting SQL.

Comment: If there are many tables I think copying results is time-consuming.

Answer (score 2):

Get counts of all tables in a schema and order by desc

```
select 'with tmp(table_name, row_number) as (' from dual 
union all 
select 'select '''||table_name||''',count(*) from '||table_name||' union  ' from USER_TABLES 
union all
select 'select '''',0 from dual) select table_name,row_number from tmp order by row_number desc ;' from dual;
```

Copy the entire result and  execute

Answer (score 1):

You have to use execute immediate (dynamic sql).

```
DECLARE 
v_owner varchar2(40); 
v_table_name varchar2(40); 
cursor get_tables is 
select distinct table_name,user 
from user_tables 
where lower(user) = 'schema_name'; 
begin 
open get_tables; 
loop
    fetch get_tables into v_table_name,v_owner; 
    EXIT WHEN get_tables%NOTFOUND;
    execute immediate 'INSERT INTO STATS_TABLE(TABLE_NAME,SCHEMA_NAME,RECORD_COUNT,CREATED) 
    SELECT ''' || v_table_name || ''' , ''' || v_owner ||''',COUNT(*),TO_DATE(SYSDATE,''DD-MON-YY'')     FROM ' || v_table_name; 
end loop;
CLOSE get_tables; 
END;
```