# Row count of all tables in a schema

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE 
    v_owner varchar2(40); 
    v_table_name varchar2(40); 
    cursor get_tables is 
        select distinct table_name
             , user 
          from user_tables 
         where lower(user) = 'schema_name'
    ; 

BEGIN 
    OPEN get_tables; 
    LOOP
        FETCH get_tables
         INTO v_table_name
            , v_owner
            ; 
        EXIT WHEN get_tables%NOTFOUND;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
             'INSERT
                INTO STATS_TABLE
                   ( TABLE_NAME
                   , SCHEMA_NAME
                   , RECORD_COUNT
                   , CREATED
                   ) 
                     SELECT ''' 
                                || v_table_name 
                   || ''' , ''' || v_owner 
                   || ''' ,        COUNT(*)
                          ,        TO_DATE(SYSDATE,''DD-MON-YY'')
                       FROM '   || v_table_name
        ; 
    END LOOP; 
    CLOSE get_tables; 
END;
```

I am using this to get row counts of all tables in a schema. I got this query from stackoverflow.

I ran this as a procedure its successfully compiled but i am unable to view the result y is it so?

I am new to pl/sql can anyone explain what does the select statement do after the excute immediate query I am unable to understand the logic behind.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get counts of all tables in a schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704808/get-counts-of-all-tables-in-a-schema)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select TABLE_NAME, NUM_ROWS from dba_tables where owner = 'xxxxx'
```

Comment: Analyze the target schema first so num_rows is up to date.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply get row count against tables by:

```
select owner, table_name, nvl(num_rows,-1) 
from all_tables 
order by nvl(num_rows,-1) desc
```

https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_EPJLBHYMPOPAGL9PQAV7XH14Q.html

Answer (score 0):

The row counts are inserted into a table name `STATS_TABLE`. You need to run a

```
select *
from stats_table
```

after running the procedure

Comment: to be more specific -> `gather_schama_stats('u1'); select num_rows from all_tables where owner = 'U1';`

Answer (score 0):

Well, user_tables does not have a user column, so that query is invalid. Always test the queries in isolation -- you probably want `all_tables` or `dba_tables`. Also, do you think you need a `DISTINCT` on that query?

Use an implicit cursor instead of an explicit one wherever you can -- less code, less error prone in coding, and faster.

Do not store dates as character types -- you just insert `sysdate`, not a representation of it as a string.

Don't prefix variable names with "v_" -- just namespace them with the procedure or block name.

The `Execute Immediate` constructs a SQL statement that performs an `insert into` the stats_table (why does it have the word "table" in the name? That's redundant, surely?)

The query will be constructed as something like:

```
INSERT INTO STATS_TABLE
     (   TABLE_NAME
       , SCHEMA_NAME
       , RECORD_COUNT
       , CREATED
     ) 
SELECT 'MY_TABLE_NAME' , 'MY_USERNAME' , COUNT(*) , SYSDATE
FROM MY_TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: There is never a need to convert sysdate to a date - it already is a date. Just "SELECT 'MY_TABLE_NAME' , 'MY_USERNAME' , COUNT(*) , SYSDATE"

Comment: Oh yes ... I guess I just copied that from the OP. I'll edit it out.

Answer (score 0):

This procedure is running successfully

```
DECLARE
  v_owner      varchar2(40);
  v_table_name varchar2(40);
  cursor get_tables is
    select distinct table_name, user
      from user_tables
     where lower(user) = 'coreown'  ;

BEGIN
  OPEN get_tables;
  LOOP
    FETCH get_tables
      INTO v_table_name, v_owner;
    EXIT WHEN get_tables%NOTFOUND;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT
                INTO STATS_TABLE
                   ( TABLE_NAME
                   , SCHEMA_NAME
                   , RECORD_COUNT
                   , CREATED
                   ) 
                     SELECT ''' || v_table_name ||
                      ''' , ''' || v_owner || ''' ,        COUNT(*)
                          ,        TO_DATE(SYSDATE,''DD-MON-YY'')
                       FROM ' || v_table_name;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE get_tables;
END;
/
```

I tried at my end.

After executing USE `COMMIT`.So that it will save the change is DB.
Then check again.