# Is it possible to use column values to determine the tablename in a from clause of a subselect?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to run a query that uses a column value (in which a tablename is stored) to determine the tablename in a from clause of a subselect.

Something like that:

> SELECT column_with_tablename,
>
> (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM **VALUEOF(column_with_tablename)**) as
>   numberofitems
>
> FROM table1

I know that this is very fragile but i need it work.
(I inherited a database that stores tablenames in a column)

Is there a way ?

Comment: You can do this in PL/SQL with an `execute` statement.  You cannot do it directly in a single query.

Comment: are you using plsql ?

Comment: I can use plsql, but i am not sure if i can create a view using plsql?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for a pure sql solution, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10705088/701753)

```
select column_with_tablename,
       to_number(extractvalue(xmltype
         (dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '||column_with_tablename)
         ),'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) as count
from table1
```