# How to determine row count for all tables in an Oracle Schema

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I tried below query :

select table_name,
 to_number(extractvalue(xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml(‘select count(*) c from ‘||table_name)),’/ROWSET/ROW/C’)) as count
 from user_tables

But, I am getting following error.

ORA-00911: invalid character
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
*Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
           Reference Manual.
*Action:
Error at Line: 76 Column: 52

I am new to oracle. So, Can anyone please let me know the possible way to get the exact row count of all the tables in particular schema.

P.S.  I tried below query for all_tables. But, I got to know that the below query is based on the statistics and it may not give exact result.

select owner, table_name, num_rows,LAST_ANALYZED  from all_tables where OWNER = 'XYZ'
and TABLE_NAME = 'APPLICATION' order by table_name asc;

Comment: It is not a duplicate question. I tried those answers as well. But,I don't want to use All_table because it is not giving me exact count. It gives counts based on LAST_ANALYZED

Comment: Do you have a `table_name` in `user_tables` that starts with a character other than letters, numbers, $, #, or _?  If you have case-sensitive identifiers (shudder) then you'd need to double quote the table name.

Comment: Have you tried the 2nd answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10705088/6827719 that looks like what you're looking for