# Rows counts are not matching after migration from Oracle to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, migration

I migrated database from oracle to Sql server using sqlmigration(SSMA) tool. 
After migration, report say 100% successfully migrated but the row counts are more than oracle in Sql Server. I cant figure out why its showing more row counts than oracle. Please Help

Comment: How are you cross checking row counts in the source (oracle) and target (sql server) table(s)? Can you share row count SQLs? is this mismatch in one table or many?

Comment: I am not using any query to match the row counts. I am using properties. its more than one tables. In oracle i am using Pl /sql developer. I  right click on table and properties shows Num_Rows in oracle . In sql server when i right click on table properties---> Storage --- Row count. When i match num_rows and row counts they are not matching. Sql Server showing more row counts than oracle num_rows.

Comment: Rownum stats may be stale. perform like -> 

-- Source
select count(1) from table_source; 

-- Target
select count(1) from table_target;

Comment: But this is static database. I mean no insert or any update. This is only one server we have in oracle and we are trying to migrate in sql server

Comment: Thanks! when i use select count(1) from table_souce. its giving me correct row counts.

Comment: Does it hurt to run SQLs and verify the count b/w source and target?  As I said, the way you are checking is not the right approach. The rownum information does not get refreshed after a large DML operation. I am typically an Oracle DBA and have not worked in SQL server recently but the concept is same. You need to refresh it to get real time rownum or other optimiser statistics.

Comment: Good! Hope to see the question marked 'answered' ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

perform row count like ->

-- Source

```
select count(1) from table_source;
```

-- Target

```
select count(1) from table_target;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check row counts of all the tables in sql server using below query

```
SELECT
    t.name, i.rows
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sysindexes i
    ON t.object_id = i.id
WHERE i.indid < 2
```

Similarly for oracle you can use this query

[Get counts of all tables in a schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704808/get-counts-of-all-tables-in-a-schema)

and you can compare