# ERROR :Table or view not found while running this query

Tags: oracle

```
select
  user_tables.table_name,
   to_number(
   extractvalue(
      xmltype(
         dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '||user_tables.table_name))
    ,'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) count

from all_tables user_tables 
   inner join all_tab_columns col on col.table_name=user_tables.table_name 
where col.column_name='EMPLOYEE_ID'
order by 
   user_tables.table_name;
```

Comment: Might be you don't have the access on all_tables.

Comment: Probably, but - why? Access to ALL_ views is granted *by default*, is it not? Anyway, @Anand: what happens if you switch to USER_TABLES and USER_TAB_COLUMNS (instead of ALL_)?

Comment: Oracle does not allow table names to be passed dynamically. I do not know what dbms_xmlgen.getxml does. If you are trying to run the SQL passed into this dynamically, it will not work using dynamic table names. The Optimizer cannot parse this successfully.

Comment: @ArtBajji - [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10705088/266304) does work; as long as objects are qualified properly *8-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are querying `all_tables`, which will give you the names of tables that you have access to in other schemas as well as those you own. But you are not qualifying the table name with the schema name. You need to include that in the `getxml()` call:

```
xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '
   || '"' || user_tables.owner || '"."' || user_tables.table_name || '"'))
```

I've also quoted the schema and table names just in case you have any with quoted identifiers (mixed case or illegal characters in the stored table name).

You are also getting (or could get) duplicates, again because of the owner; if the same table name exists in multiple schemas the join will link them all; so include the owner in the join:

```
...
from all_tables user_tables 
inner join all_tab_columns col
on col.owner = user_tables.owner and col.table_name = user_tables.table_name 
where col.column_name='EMPLOYEE_ID'
...
```

I'd also include the owner in the output, pick a less confusing table alias, and use [XMLQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/XMLQUERY.html) instead of the deprecated `extractvalue()`:

```
select
  tabs.owner,
  tabs.table_name,
  to_number(
    xmlquery('/ROWSET/ROW/C/text()' passing
      xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '
         || '"' || tabs.owner || '"."' || tabs.table_name || '"'))
    returning content)) count
from all_tables tabs
inner join all_tab_columns cols
on cols.owner = tabs.owner and cols.table_name = tabs.table_name 
where cols.column_name = 'EMPLOYEE_ID'
order by tabs.owner, tabs.table_name;
```

which on a pretty-vanilla 12cR2 instance connected as HR gives:

```
OWNER                          TABLE_NAME                          COUNT
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----------
APEX_050100                    WWV_FLOW_FND_USER                       3
HR                             EMPLOYEES                             107
HR                             JOB_HISTORY                            10
HRREST                         EMPLOYEES                             107
HRREST                         JOB_HISTORY                            10
OBE                            OEHR_EMPLOYEES                        107
OBE                            OEHR_JOB_HISTORY                       11

7 rows selected.
```

With your original code I'd get the same error you did, because it would try to count rows in - for instance - the `OEHR_EMPLOYEES` table, which is not in my schema. I'd see the same error directly querying `from OEHR_EMPLOYEES`, but I'd be OK with `from OBE.OEHR_EMPLOYEES`. My modification adds that schema name to the count query. And if it got that far, it would count the rows in *my* `EMPLOYEES` table four times because of the loose join, rather than mine once and HRREST's once.