# How to create a table to store list of table names and the table count?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a table that store table names and count of the table.

I already have the list of tables. How to use this list to get all the count for the tables?

The result should be like this:

```
TABLE_NAME   NUM_ROWS
------------ --------
tableName1   result from select count(*) from tableName1     
...
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Count of tables means total no of table in that list or count of records in that table???

Comment: [Like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10705088/266304)

Comment: means : select count(*) from table_name;

Comment: @user228: I think that's what Alex's example does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Quick and Dirty solution try.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, NUM_ROWS
FROM USER_TABLES
```

Oracle stores a wealth of metadata information. 
You can query into the metadata to get a reasonable estimate.
The actual number of rows can be off depending on when the table was last analyzed and how often the table is updated..

If that is not a viable option, you will need to write a pl/sql procedure to loop through the tables (querying USER_TABLES) and using something like EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to select the count of the number of rows on that table.