# Check which views have rows

Tags: sql, database, oracle, view

I have a database with 300+ views, on which most of the views are empty.
I need to know which views have rows.
Is there a query to check which of these views have rows?

Comment: A view doesn't really have rows, it's just a stored query, so there is no equivalent of the `num_rows` you can use as a rough guide for tables. But you can just query them all and count; [this XML query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10705088/266304) should do the trick, just change 'table' to 'view' throughout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT owner, view_name, cnt              
FROM all_views, XMLTABLE('/ROWSET/ROW' passing (
             dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(REPLACE(REPLACE(
         'select COUNT(*) AS cnt from "<owner>"."<table_name>"', '<owner>', owner)
             , '<table_name>', view_name))) COLUMNS cnt INT)
WHERE cnt > 0;
```

---

EDIT:

If we want only to check if view has rows we could exchange `COUNT` with `EXISTS`. This should also improve performance.

```
SELECT owner, view_name, has_rows            
FROM all_views, XMLTABLE('/ROWSET/ROW' passing (
             dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(REPLACE(REPLACE(
              'select CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 from "<owner>"."<table_name>") 
              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS has_rows FROM dual', '<owner>', owner)
             , '<table_name>', view_name))) COLUMNS has_rows INT)
WHERE has_rows > 0;
```

Comment: Good answer, but in my database, that would (A) take forever and (B) give misleading results because a lot of the views do not return rows unless the user's `SYS_CONTEXT()` is initialized first.

Comment: You could add a `rownum` filter to the count query which might improve things a bit, if the OP only cares about non-zero counts rather than the actual number of rows returned. That doesn't help with Matthew's other point, of course... but that might not apply for the OP.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak I agree that  RLS/context will change results. I could exchange COUNT(*) with EXISTS to make it faster a bit.

Comment: `select CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 from "<owner>"."<table_name>") 
              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS has_rows FROM dual` is a gem, this has significantly improved checks for me on whether a view has rows or not. My stored procedure has gone from minutes down to seconds

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way, other than query each one.

And even that is not perfect, since the query that defines a view could refer to things like `USER` or `SYS_CONTEXT()`.  Or there could be row-level security (`DBMS_RLS`) policies on the underlying tables of a view.  What that all means is that a view might not have any rows for you, but could very well have rows for another user at the exact same moment.

Bottom line, there is no way.