# How to Get max created date for tables selected from all_tab_columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have selected (from all_tab_columns) some tables and columns of DATE datatype. I would like to know the MAX date for each table. Could you help me out with a dynamic way to do it? Table names and column names could be different depending on my where clause when selecting from all_tab_columns.

Sample data:

```sql
WITH
    tabs (TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE) AS
        (
            Select 'A_ZR_6', 'CREATED_DATE', 'DATE' From dual Union All
            Select 'A_ZR_8', 'CREATEDDATE', 'DATE' From dual Union All
            Select 'A_ZR_2', 'CREATED_DATE', 'DATE' From dual Union All
            Select 'A_ZR_4', 'CREATED_DATE', 'DATE' From dual Union All
            Select 'A_ZR_9', 'CREATED_DATE', 'DATE' From dual 
        )
```

| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A_ZR_6 | CREATED_DATE | DATE |
| A_ZR_8 | CREATEDDATE | DATE |
| A_ZR_2 | CREATED_DATE | DATE |
| A_ZR_4 | CREATED_DATE | DATE |
| A_ZR_9 | CREATED_DATE | DATE |

The expected result should look like here:

| TABLE_NAME | MAX_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| A_ZR_6 | 07-NOV-22 |
| A_ZR_8 | 12-DEC-22 |
| A_ZR_2 | 03-OCT-22 |
| A_ZR_4 | 01-NOV-22 |
| A_ZR_9 | 31-DEC-22 |

CODE:

```
select 
  table_name,
  column_name 
from
  all_tab_columns 
where 
  owner='ABC' and 
  table_name not like 'V_%' and
  lower(column_name) like '%create%' and 
  lower(column_name) like '%date%' 
  
 group by
   table_name,
   column_name
```

Comment: What have you tried ?  Did you get any errors ? Where did you get stuck ?

Comment: You will need to use some form of dynamic SQL. You could try to adapt [this kind of trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69932443/266304), adding the count function to the dynamic SQL string.

Comment: You want something like `select max(createddate) from b_gbo_project2 union all select max(created_date) from b_sox_control_raid_log union all ...`. Would it by "dynamic" enough to simply paste your result into an editor and use search/replace to generate that query? Or to select the concatenated string right away? Otherwise (i.e. if you want to run the final query without human interaction) use a programming language for that, e.g. PL/SQL.

Comment: You should avoid posting image, it's quite unpractical to read. When posting question related to sql, it's very useful to give the database schema for other reader to better understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the only method that you can use is a PL/SQL program because the name of table in a SQL statement Oracle cannot dynamic:

```
SET LINE 100;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE

CURSOR QCursor is
    SELECT
           X.table_name, 
           'SELECT MAX(' || X.column_name || ') from ' || owner || '.' || X.table_name as query   
      FROM (
            SELECT
                   owner,
                   table_name,
                   column_name 
              FROM
                   all_tab_columns 
             WHERE 
                   owner = 'ABC'
               AND table_name not like 'V_%' 
               AND lower(column_name) like '%create%' 
               AND lower(column_name) like '%date%' 
             GROUP BY owner,
                      table_name,
                      column_name 
           ) X;
         
--# RIGA DEL CURSORE CONTROLLO
ROW_QCursor  QCursor%ROWTYPE;

v_max_date   DATE;


BEGIN

   DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000000);
   
   OPEN ROW_QCursor;
   
   LOOP

       FETCH QCursor INTO ROW_QCursor;
       EXIT WHEN QCursor%NOTFOUND;

       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ROW_QCursor.query INTO v_max_date;
       
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Table_name :' || ROW_QCursor.table_name || ' Max date is : ' || v_max_date);

   END LOOP;
   
   CLOSE ROW_QCursor;
   
END;
/
```

Alternatively, if the query is manually (es. Sql Developer) you can run this query:

```
select 
       X.table_name, 
       'SELECT MAX(' || X.column_name || ') from ' || owner || '.' || X.table_name as query   
from (
      select 
             owner,
             table_name,
             column_name 
        from
             all_tab_columns 
       where 
             owner = 'ABC'
         and table_name not like 'V_%' 
         and lower(column_name) like '%create%' 
         and lower(column_name) like '%date%' 
       group by owner,
                table_name,
                column_name 
     ) X;
```

and then copy the output and execute manually:

```
TABLE_ QUERY                                   
------ ----------------------------------------
A_ZR_2 SELECT MAX(CREATED_DATE) from ABC.A_ZR_2
A_ZR_9 SELECT MAX(CREATED_DATE) from ABC.A_ZR_9
A_ZR_8 SELECT MAX(CREATED_DATE) from ABC.A_ZR_8
A_ZR_6 SELECT MAX(CREATED_DATE) from ABC.A_ZR_6
A_ZR_4 SELECT MAX(CREATED_DATE) from ABC.A_ZR_4
```

I hope I was helpful.

Thank you.